# Where is my trash can in lubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

i can't find the trash

Do I miss something??

[image]

Comment: I'm fairly certain the Trash doesn't have a shortcut in the file browser by default. Check your desktop or launcher (~ taskbar) for the trash icon.

Comment: Actually, it does.  See below.

Comment: mind explaining why this question is downvoted?

Comment: No Idea.  Legit question as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erm, you kinda did miss something.  It's there, by default, unless you removed it somehow.  Just click where it says "Directory Tree" and select "Places" from the drop-down menu.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Enter the location `trash:///`, then bookmark it.

Comment: Not required, it's there already.