# No Trash Can In Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I have Lubuntu running on top of Ubuntu 14.04 on my VPS.

However, I can't find the `Trash Can` and when I try to go to `trash:///` it says `Operation not supported`.

Somebody please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: I've got Lubuntu Xenial in a VM and it certainly has a Rubbish Bin on the desktop.
Opening PCManFM1.2.4 shows a Trash Can on the navigation frame.

Comment: Just a quick search and I found the below. I am hesitant to mark is as duplicate as I am not 100% sure whether it's the same. If it is the same issue, try following the instructions that @Organic Marble suggested.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/684782/where-is-my-trash-can-in-lubuntu-14-04

Comment: @proprocastinator No, it's not the same. Mine is already set to Places

Comment: Are you using a root user? Or are you running pcmanfm with sudo rights? Because trash is not supported if you are root (haven't understood why) so if that's the case you must access it through `~/.local/share/Trash` (the files folder has the deleted files).

Comment: @ThanosApostolou No, I'm accessing it as a sudo user, I'm not root. It still won't work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? It just recently started happening to me too!